# Mysql query to find the blank word by comparing 2 sentences

Tags: mysql, compare

I have 2 fields in one mysql table.
One field has full sentence and another field has the same sentence but with one word replaced by "**_**". How I can find the replaced word using mysql query?

Example:
Field1: We aim for an 85% success rate.
Field2: We **_** for an 85% success rate.

I need a query which can find the word "aim" comparing both 2 sentences.

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? Why don't you put the replaced word in a separate column when you generate these sentences so that you can just ask for that column instead of trying to parse and compare the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT REVERSE(
         SUBSTR(
           REVERSE(SUBSTR(Field1 FROM INSTR(Field2, '_')))
         FROM
           INSTR(REVERSE(Field2), '_'))
       )
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( field1,
               POSITION( '_' IN field2 ),
               LENGTH( field1 ) - LENGTH( field2 ) + 1 );
```